# How does moving the view controller's code to presenter make it easier to unit test in VIPER?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, viper-architecture

I have read in **VIPER** blogs that moving view controller's code to `Presenter` codes makes it easy to unit test. The reason given in the blogs was that the `Presenter` doesn't have any **UIKit** related code in it.

How does this make it easier to unit test. Can any one please explain this in detail? Or is there any other advantage of this apart from avoiding **Massive View Controller** problem?

Comment: You can just test your single functions without having to rely on uikit,loading the whole viewcontroller lifecycle and rendering of uiviews etc.

Comment: Yes. My doubt is that you can do this even when the function is inside view controller. Thats why I asked is there any problem with loading view hierarchy during unit testing? Is that very costly? And one thing to note is that we are justing loading the view hierarchy and we are not rendering it. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem in unit testing is how to *mock* something. You want to test a method but that method is calling 3 other methods and you don't want to test these 3 methods, therefore you want to mock them to return some fixed value.

This is pretty easy in languages like Javascript, where you can substitute a method on any object or in Objective-C where you can do the same (although with a bit more difficulty).

This is not easy in a language like Swift. Therefore Viper came with the idea to split view controller into units (e.g. Presenter, Interactor, View, Router) and every unit has its own protocol. Now to mock one the units you can just implement the protocol and use it instead of the real Presenter or View.

(you can actually use some tools to generate the mocks for you dynamically in tests)

That makes unit testing much much easier.

However note that unit testing UI is never easy. UI usually operates in terms that are difficult to unit test and unit testing UI almost always means that you will be duplicating a lot of your app code in unit tests. UI is more commonly tested via integration tests (e.g. automatic clicking and validating what is visible on the screen).

Viper is not a bad architecture. Separation of concerns is something that many programmers struggle with and it's not a bad idea to have *strict* architectural rules. With complex screens you still won't be able to avoid big controllers but at least you will be forced to move some code out of the controller.

Massive View Controllers are not a problem of the MVC pattern. They are a problem of bad separation of concerns and strict rules in Viper help to avoid that.

Comment: Thank you.   My doubt was that we can still instantiate view controller either from storyboard or from  xib file and have its view hierarchy loaded. With this we can check like after some operation is performed whether our ui elements have proper value set or not. What is the problem with this? Is loading view controller during unit testing considered as heavy operation? And for mocking we can have some of the methods overridden in mocked subclass. Can you please specify the problem with this?

Comment: The only advantage I see in moving UI related business logic to Presenter is to reduce the number of lines in view controller(I,e to avoid Massive Controller Problem). Can you please correct me if I am wrong?